# WP Snippet to Hide Theme Editor In Dashboard Only Works On LocalHost Site

Tags: themes, security, dashboard, editor

I want to remove the Theme Editor in the WP Dashboard that is located under Dashboard > Appearance > Theme Editor. The code I'm using in my `config.php` file in the root of my site is :

`define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true);`

Which I place just before the line:

`/*That’s all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`

This works on the localhost installation, but not on the live site?

Comment: Can I know that which hosting provider you are using?

Comment: @AshokDhaudk Siteground

Comment: Can you confirm that define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT', true); - it's added inside wp-config.php in live?

Comment: Hi @AshokDhaudk this was the problem. If you do that as an answer I'll mark it as correct

Comment: Hi Chewy, can you create clone of same site on same hosting but under different folder and provide me access to that cloned site?

Comment: You have to check file permission of that file because I have seen that some hosting provider don't allow that file to modify so they set file permission to readable only. Check that one first.